# Pyspark - randomSplit on RDD w/ replacement or without?

Tags: pyspark

I need to split an RDD into training, validation, and test set - I am using the randomSplit method to do it. I have three questions:

1. Is this the best method to use for splitting into test, validation, training set?
2. I assume this is truly splitting the data (sampling without replacement) and not taking three independent samples (sampling with replacement)?

**(trainData, valData, testData) = dataRDD.randomSplit([0.6, 0.2, 0.2])**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- it is a valid method of splitting data in Spark.
- it creates data splits not independent samples.